# How do we create Domo Back Button?

Tags: javascript, button, assets, back, domo

I have creating a domo assets for back button in domo but the problem is the back button won't work
the back button cannot by pass the iframe which the back button is inside the card frame.

Any code that I can use for this? Your help much will appreciated. Thanks!

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
    <base target="_parent">
  </head>
    <!-- <a id="back-button" target="_parent" href="#"><span>&#8592;</span> Back</a> -->

    <a id="back-button" href="#"','"target="_parent"><span>&#8592;</span> Back</a>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="domo.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

INSIDE APP.JS

document.getElementById("back-button").top.history.back()

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. please take a while and read [ask] with [mre]. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

The domoapp `iframe` is in a sandbox and does not give you access to manipulate the parent. That said, what are you trying to do? If you can keep track of what page "back" should be navigating to, you can use `domo.navigate()` and navigate to a particular page.